# Is there any relation between monsters and Gracelings?

Tags: seven-kingdoms

In the Seven Kingdoms series by Kristin Cashore, we first are introduced to Gracelings, each of whom has a particular gift (for survival, cooking, mind control, whatever), and is distinguished by their different-colored eyes, often of an unusual color. As I recall, it's not heritable.

Meanwhile, across the mountains, there are monstrous humans and animals, who have unusually colored hair and feathers, whose appearance attracts others, and who possess mental powers. As I recall, their powers *are* heritable, possibly perfectly so—I can't remember what caused the huge population decrease in human monsters; possibly predation by non-human monsters.

Still, the similarity of having unusually colored eyes or hair is striking. And as an additional tantalizing point, animal monsters had a particular desire to eat Immiker (later Leck), much as they felt toward Fire and other monsters. In fact, *Seasparrow* mentions that Gracelings in general attract more attention from animal monsters, not just Immiker (whose Grace was, after all, closer to the monsters' abilities).

To cap it all off, in *Winterkeep*, we are introduced to yet another part of the same world, which has foxes with somewhat unusual fur colors and minor telepathic abilities, and in *Seasparrow*, we see that the foxes seem largely unaffected by the mental lure of monstrous animals—and that the polar bears that live north of Pikkia have unusually closed minds.

Is there any relationship between the phenomena that produce these various groups?